# Keras and Python 3.6: Error when checking input for Sequential model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

Somehow I found a very strange bug in the Keras library.

My learning method includes a three-layer neural network: an input layer with 130,517 units (input size), a hidden layer of 10,000, and an output layer of 2 units.

During the code, I ran a batch learning (I used `partial_fit` function) but the code repeatedly threw the same Error:

> {ValueError} Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   shape (130517,) but got array with shape (1,)

I checked the input dimension again, and found that it was indeed as I thought, having 130,517 dimensions.

Here is a picture of variables at debugging, and as you can see, the shape of `np.array(X[0])` is 130,517:

[image]

For any case, I attached the code of initialization of the Neural Network, and the code of the call to `partial_fit`:

```
    def initClassifier(self):
       self.classifier.add(Dense(100000, input_dim=130517, activation='relu'))
       self.classifier.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
       self.classifier.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


    def partial_fit(self, X, y, classes):
        self.classifier.train_on_batch(np.array(X[0]), np.array(y))
```

Does anyone have a solution? 
Could it be a bug in the Keras code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On training, Keras expects your data to include a dimension for the batch size. In your case, this means the data should be of shape `(batch_size, 130517)`. However, you are passing a `np array` of shape `(130517)`, which is causing your error. You can reshape your data to include a batch shape as follows:

`X_reshaped = X[0].reshape(1, -1)`

Comment: Thank you! I tried to solve the problem for more than two hours